# Calling a function as a go routine produces different call stack from go routine as anonymous func

Tags: go, runtime, goroutine, callstack

I have a function named PrintCaller() which calls runtime.Caller() and skipping one frame to obtain and print the callers (of PrintCaller's) file name and line number. This works as expected when ran synchronously, and if called asynchronous as an anonymous function. However, if ran with just the `go` keyword, the stack frame of the caller is replaced with some internal function call.

For example, this is the function:

```
func printCaller(wait chan bool) {
    _, fileName, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    fmt.Printf("Filename: %s, line: %d\n", fileName, line)
}
```

If I call is like this:

```
func main() {
    printCaller()
    go func(){printCaller()}()
    go printCaller()
}
```

The output is:

```
Filename: /tmp/sandbox297971268/prog.go, line: 19
Filename: /tmp/sandbox297971268/prog.go, line: 22
Filename: /usr/local/go-faketime/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s, line: 1374
```

Working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/Jv21SVDY2Ln

Why does this happen when I call `go PrintCaller()`, but not when I call `go func(){PrintCaller()}()`? Also, is there any way to make this work using `go PrintCaller()`?

Comment: The caller *is* the assembly-language function shown in the stack trace. That's how goroutines get called: there's an assembly stub that calls them. When you define a closure that calls your function and invoke that with `go func() { ... }`, it's the same stub calling your closure, `func() { ... }`, but now your closure calls your `PrintCaller` so the caller you see is the closure.

Comment: "is there any way to make this work using go PrintCaller()?" No.

Comment: @torek That makes sense, thanks for the explanation! Feel free to add that as an answer and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you've seen is what one would expect, given the inner workings of the Go runtime system:

- A goroutine, such as the main one that calls your own `main` in package `main`, but also including routines started by `go somefunc()`, is actually called *from* some machine-specific startup routine.  On the playground that's the one in `src/runtime/asm_amd64.s`.
- When you define a closure, such as:

  ```
  f := func() {
      // code
  }
  ```

  this creates an anonymous function.  Calling it:

  ```
  f()
  ```

  calls that anonymous function, from whatever the caller is.  This is true regardless of whether the closure is assigned to a variable (as with `f` above) or just called right away, or later with `defer`, or whatever:

  ```
  defer func() {
      // code ...
  }()
  ```
- So, writing:

  ```
  go func() {
      // code ...
  }()
  ```

  simply calls the anonymous function here from that same machine-specific startup.  If *that function* then calls your `printCaller` function, which uses `runtime.Caller(1)` to skip over your `printCaller` function and find its caller, it finds the anonymous function:

  ```
  Filename: /tmp/sandbox297971268/prog.go, line: 22
  ```

  for instance.
- But when you write:

  ```
  go printCaller()
  ```

  you are invoking the function named `printCaller` from the machine-specific goroutine startup code.

Since `printCaller` prints the name of its caller, which is this machine-specific startup code, that's what you see.

There's a big caveat here and that is that `runtime.Caller` is allowed to fail.  That's why it returns a boolean `ok` along with the `pc uintptr, file string, line int` values.  There's no guarantee that the machine-specific assembly caller will be find-able.